# Setup .exe file download and run only downloaded pc only

Tags: installation

I have 1 Setup .exe file download and run only downloaded pc only 
otherwise it does not execute..!!!

For example i have a java project and i make it .exe file and uploaded to any file hosting site

when someone download that file it should run only that machine

Comment: Your quertion is hard to understaand. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible without server-side code serving different downloads to each downloader. and even with that it is hard to get right and usable and probably not worth the effort.